# How to convert a String to a dictionary list

Tags: python

Let's say we have String like this:

```
string = "[{'Chr': 'chrX', 'Start': 107844640, 'End': 107844640}, {'Chr': 'chrY', 'Start': 107844641, 'End': 107844641}]"
```

The goal is to convert that string into a list of dictionaries.

For now I have only managed to convert the String into a list:

```
str1 = string.replace(']','').replace('[','')
l = str1.replace('"','').split(",")
```

Unfortunately this adds unwanted characters like '""', how could I get rid of the undesired characters and get the desired result?

Comment: `ast.literal_eval(string)`

Comment: Hmmm, like @MarkTolonen humbly commented before the scavengers hit the "Post *your* answer" button, **you already have a list of dict**, just written as a string, so of course, literal evaluation of this string stored into a variable = a list of dictionaries...

Comment: Cheknov :  I've stolen @MarkTolonen 's comment and clarified how to get your string into a variable of type *list of dictionaries* as you asked for. Feel free to mark it as the "answer".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I'll jump on the stealing wagon as well, as it seems the OP didn't fully get the "answer".

So, you basically already have a list of dictionaries, just defined in a variable of type string.
Use `ast` to get the literal value from the string and voila, a list of dictionaries.

```py
import ast

dict_string = "[{'Chr': 'chrX', 'Start': 107844640, 'End': 107844640}, {'Chr': 'chrY', 'Start': 107844641, 'End': 107844641}]"
dict_list = ast.literal_eval(dict_string)

# dict_list is now a list of dictionaries
```

Answer (score 2):

```
import ast

string = "[{'Chr': 'chrX', 'Start': 107844640, 'End': 107844640}, {'Chr': 'chrY', 'Start': 107844641, 'End': 107844641}]"

# ast.literal_eval(string)

for i in ast.literal_eval(string):
    print(i)
```

Comment: Perhaps I'm misunderstanding, but this print out two `dict` and not a `list` of `dict`

Comment: Yeah, so in order to make it work as I expect, we have to create a new list and append each dict to the list. The solution partially solved my problem but was enough to get inspiration and finish implementing the code.

Comment: @Cheknov See my answer. It is easier than you think, just assign the result from the `ast` literal parser to a variable. Feel free to mark my answer as the answer, as it actually answers what you asked for. (I know, cheap)

Answer (score 1):

My immediate solution, and as Mark Tolonen says, `ast.literal_eval(string)` is the most built-in pythonic way without using `exec()`.